What is the most efficient way to create a list of two different types of objects with a common parent type?
I have a Dog class and a Cat class. I want to create a list that has 2 dogs and then 1 cat over and over again until we run out of dogs. The list should sort the dogs by their order. What is the most efficient way to do this in Kotlin?
Here is my current code that is working:
enum class CatBreed { MAINE_COON, BALINESE, BENGAL }
enum class DogBreed { ITALIAN_GREYHOUND, BEAGLE, AKITA, POMERANIAN, SHIH_TZU, DACHSHUND }
data class Dog(val breed: DogBreed, val order: Int)
data class Cat(val breed: CatBreed)
abstract class PetsItem
data class DogItem(val dog: Dog) : PetsItem()
data class CatItem(val cat: Cat) : PetsItem()

var petsList = arrayListOf<PetsItem>()
val dogs = arrayListOf(Dog(ITALIAN_GREYHOUND, 3), Dog(BEAGLE, 2), Dog(AKITA, 1), Dog(POMERANIAN, 6), Dog(SHIH_TZU, 5), Dog(DACHSHUND, 4))
val cats = arrayListOf(Cat(MAINE_COON), Cat(BALINESE), Cat(BENGAL))

val orderedDogs = ArrayList(dogs.asSequence()
    .sortedBy { it.order }
    .toList())

for ((index, dog) in orderedDogs.withIndex()) {
    petsList.add(DogItem(dog = dog))
    if (index % 2 == 1) {
        if (cats.isNotEmpty()) {
            petsList.add(CatItem(cat = cats.removeAt(0)))
        }
    }
}

I have this code:
val list = ArrayList(dogs.asSequence()
    .sortBy { it.order }
    .map { DogItem(dog = it) }
    .toList())

Which seems very efficient at turning Dog objects into DogItem objects. But I can't figure out how to modify it to allow for Cats as well.
So does anyone know if there is a more efficient way to create the list as I want it than what I'm currently doing?

It could be done in a quite clean way if not for the requirement that the number of dogs and cats doesn't have to match. With all these corner cases that we may have less dogs than cats, less cats than dogs, odd or even number of dogs, etc. I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way than your current solution. Just please be aware removing the first item from the array list may be terribly slow. Consider using a linked list, a deque/queue or accessing cats by the index.

I think for such small lists that this is sufficiently efficient:
val petsList: List<PetsItem> = dogs
    .sortedBy(Dog::order)
    .map(::DogItem)
    .zip2To1(cats.map(::CatItem))

Although it's probably possible to zip the list of dogs with the list of cats using only built-in functions, to respect all edge-cases would be quite difficult and probably inefficient. That's why I used a custom-tailored function:
fun <T> Iterable<T>.zip2To1(other: Iterable<T>): List<T> {
    val iteratorThis = iterator()
    val iteratorOther = other.iterator()
    if (!iteratorThis.hasNext()) return emptyList()
    if (!iteratorOther.hasNext()) return if (this is List) this else this.toList()
    val result = mutableListOf<T>()

    result.add(iteratorThis.next())
    while (iteratorThis.hasNext()) {
        result.add(iteratorThis.next())
        result.add(iteratorOther.next())
        if (!iteratorOther.hasNext()) iteratorThis.forEachRemaining { result.add(it) }
        if (iteratorThis.hasNext()) result.add(iteratorThis.next())
    }

    return result
}

This will be a bit more efficient than your for loop since it doesn't need to remove elements from a mutable cats list, it just iterates both lists together. It also has the benefit that your lists can be immutable, and this can be easily chained together with other list transformations.
This solution only uses list operations, in contrast to the sequences you used in your example. Sequences are great when you have many elements and long transformation chains because the elements are not copied to a new list and iterated again on each transformation, it is all done in one iteration. It does incur an additional cost to set them up, though, since they are coroutine-based and need to switch back and forth when a sequence yields a new value (and then suspends). Without having actually benchmarked it, I would still assume for this specific case that lists will be much better suited.
That said, You can easily switch everything to sequences:
val dogs = sequenceOf(...)
val cats = sequenceOf(...)

And that's it. petsList doesn't need to be touched because the standard lib provides (mostly) the same transformation functions for sequences as it does for lists. If you want the resulting sequence converted to a list in the end you just need to append a .toList(). The only thing that you are now missing is a custom zip2To1 function for sequences. Well, here it is:
fun <T> Sequence<T>.zip2To1(other: Sequence<T>): Sequence<T> {
    val iteratorThis = iterator()
    val iteratorOther = other.iterator()
    if (!iteratorThis.hasNext()) return emptySequence()
    if (!iteratorOther.hasNext()) return this

    return sequence {
        yield(iteratorThis.next())
        while (iteratorThis.hasNext()) {
            yield(iteratorThis.next())
            yield(iteratorOther.next())
            if (!iteratorOther.hasNext()) yieldAll(iteratorThis)
            if (iteratorThis.hasNext()) yield(iteratorThis.next())
        }
    }
}

Closing words: Efficiency is rarely the most important goal when developing an application. The code should be as concise and clear as possibly so it can be easily undertood. That will prevent bugs and improves the maintainability.

my dog list will never have more than 6 dogs, but it can have less than 6 dogs. and my cat list will never have more than 3 cats, but it can have less than 3 cats. So I think this is perfect. Question though, are you saying that I shouldn't use this code if I ever decide to make the list much longer?

For such small lists the implementation is almost irrelevant efficiency-wise. The best option would be to use the most simplest variant. Stick with lists and standard transformation functions where possible (the first option from my answer). This will still work pretty well for longer lists (several thousands) but when it becomes "too slow" is strongly dependent on the use case: When will this be executed? Every frame on the UI thread? Then you need to keep a sharp eye on the performance. ...

... Is this only done everytime after a database or even network request? Then the runtime of this won't matter because it will only take a fraction of the time that was already spent waiting for the IO operation to finish. I would only cross that bridge when you actually run into performance problems. Don't invest too much time and effort into premature optimization. Keep it simple.

I see 2 problems here:

Sorting takes O(n * log n) on average. Which is pretty slow if the order of each element is already known.

.sortedBy { it.order }


Removing the head of ArrayList causes recalculation of the whole array. It leads to O(m^2) as you need to add all cats.

cats.removeAt(0)

To overcome these issues, you can simply use indices w/o any heavy operations:
val orderToDog = mutableMapOf<Int, Dog>()
dogs.forEach { orderToDog[it.order] = it } // 1 -> AKITA, 2 -> BEAGLE, etc

var dogIdx = 0
var catIdx = 0

while (dogIdx < dogs.size) {
    petsList.add(DogItem(orderToDog[dogIdx + 1]!!))

    if (dogIdx % 2 == 1 && catIdx < cats.size) {
        petsList.add(CatItem(cats[catIdx++]))
    }

    dogIdx++
}

This reduces Time complexity from O(n * log n + m^2) where n - # of dogs, m - # of cats to O(n + m).

this would be great, but I forgot to mention that dog's order doesn't necessarily start at 0 or 1. so orderToDog[dogIdx + 1], wouldn't always work.
